# MAUI on Windows in Visual Studio 2022 - iOS developement BouncyCastle error

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui, bouncycastle

While trying to develop an app in MAUI, Android is all done, and have connected iPhone to my PC, itunes and all that, Visual Studio throws an Error that cancels the build.
I have an Apple developer account and have setup an certificate from Apple in VS.

The error is:
**illegal object in GetInstance: Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence**

and it is pointing to file Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets at the lines where is:

```
<HotRestart.Tasks.Codesign
            AppBundlePath="$(HotRestartAppBundlePath)"
            BundleIdentifier="$(_BundleIdentifier)"
            CodeSigningPath="$(_CodeSigningPath)"
            ProvisioningProfilePath="$(_ProvisioningProfilePath)" />
```

The device is updated to current iOS with iTunes on PC, last VS 2022, I'm targeting .NET 7.0...

Any help is appriciated, thanks!

Comment: If you received a full stack trace, please provide it. What is the .NET version that you are targeting?

Comment: Thnx for your answer @peter-dettman, that's all the info I recieved. I'm targeting .NET 7.0., and no other error message.